# unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I am trying to upgrade using these below commands:
sudo apt -y update
sudo apt -y upgrade

While running the second command I am getting this error. I want to kill al the process using one single command whoever is using the file. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
First you need to find out what is upgrade's procress id.

Use below command:

```
ps -aux | grep upgrade
```

when you know that want to kill procress id number.

then run below command. Note: procress-ID-this-is-a-number is a number that mean to procress id.

```
sudo kill -9  procress-ID-this-is-a-number
```

Comment: I want to automatically get the pid and kill. Basically, I am using one shell script